# Clear input field when data is dragged and dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function that automatically clears the preset value of an input field when the user focusses on it, and puts it back on blur if the user does not input any value.

so the value of `<input type="text" value="example" />` would be set to nothing on focus.

The problem I am facing is as follows:

When I select a bit of text on the page and drag and drop it into the input field, the field will not be cleared before the dropped text is applied.

Instead the value of the input field will become: exampleLorem, opposed to just Lorem.

Is there a proper way to remove the default value right after the text is dropped into the input field?

Comment: The only safe way I can think about is using timer.. check every x milliseconds (e.g. 50) if the value has changed and if so, trigger the onchange event manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of other events you can use than **focus** and **blur**

Most interesting to this issue should be [drop](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbflwps.php), [dragenter](http://help.dottoro.com/ljccpmjk.php) and [dragleave](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbonkao.php)

Please note: in MSIE it looks like  the focus-event fires immediatly after drop, so you need a kind of flag to set on drop (and remove this flag a moment later), to handle a invocation of focus forced by drop.

Also note: unfortunately opera doesn't support those dragdrop-events

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track.

I ended up using and modifying the example on this page to achieve the result I wanted: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0480__Drag-Drop/ondropeventhandlerIE.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can clear the preset not on focus, but on hover (or mouseover)?

Comment: I tried doing this, but for some reason events like hover or mouseover did not work for the input boxes when dragging a piece of text.